# Could not find service hosting interface android.hardware.radio.config@1.0::IRadioConfig/default

Tags: android, quectel

I am integrating a Quectel EC25 into an existing Lineage ROM and am receiving the following message in dmesg

```
Could not find service hosting interface android.hardware.radio.config@1.0::IRadioConfig/default
```

What does this issue come from? I am I missing a package during build? The original Radio for this device/ROM was Qualcomm and not Quectel.

I have the following HAL definitions:

```
<hal format="hidl">
    <name>android.hardware.broadcastradio</name>
    <transport>hwbinder</transport>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <interface>
        <name>IBroadcastRadioFactory</name>
        <instance>default</instance>
    </interface>
</hal>
<hal format="hidl">
    <name>android.hardware.radio.deprecated</name>
    <transport>hwbinder</transport>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <interface>
        <name>IOemHook</name>
        <instance>slot1</instance>
    </interface>
</hal>
<hal format="hidl">
    <name>android.hardware.radio</name>
    <transport>hwbinder</transport>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <interface>
        <name>IRadio</name>
        <instance>slot1</instance>
    </interface>
</hal>
```

Source:

https://github.com/darran-kelinske-fivestars/android_device_lenovo_tb-common/blob/dff9d6c0d81b83f8541a76f7c9beccd84ea889d9/manifest.xml#L204-L230

Full log:

```
[  166.333636] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using msm_hsusb_host
[  166.444063] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=2c7c, idProduct=0125
[  166.444081] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  166.444090] usb 1-1.1: Product: Android
[  166.444100] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Android
[  166.450194] option 1-1.1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  166.451457] usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  166.455370] option 1-1.1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  166.456632] usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  166.461523] option 1-1.1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  166.462494] usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[  166.466384] option 1-1.1:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  166.467252] usb 1-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[  166.471994] qmi_wwan 1-1.1:1.4: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[  166.472015] qmi_wwan 1-1.1:1.4: Quectel EC21&EC25 work on RawIP mode
[  166.480868] qmi_wwan 1-1.1:1.4 wwan0: register 'qmi_wwan' at usb-msm_hsusb_host-1.1, WWAN/QMI device, 0000000000000000
[  168.904509] type=1400 audit(1588111305.685:263): avc: denied { open } for pid=3405 comm="getprop" path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:bluetooth_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=280 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:bluetooth_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[  168.904559] type=1400 audit(1588111332.185:475): avc: denied { getattr } for pid=618 comm="rild" path="/dev/cdc-wdm0" dev="tmpfs" ino=77796 scontext=u:r:rild:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
[  168.906456] type=1400 audit(1588111332.185:475): avc: denied { getattr } for pid=618 comm="rild" path="/dev/cdc-wdm0" dev="tmpfs" ino=77796 scontext=u:r:rild:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
[  168.906507] type=1400 audit(1588111332.189:476): avc: denied { read write } for pid=618 comm="rild" name="ttyUSB2" dev="tmpfs" ino=77794 scontext=u:r:rild:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
[  168.906670] type=1400 audit(1588111332.189:476): avc: denied { read write } for pid=618 comm="rild" name="ttyUSB2" dev="tmpfs" ino=77794 scontext=u:r:rild:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
[  168.906697] type=1400 audit(1588111332.189:477): avc: denied { open } for pid=618 comm="rild" path="/dev/ttyUSB2" dev="tmpfs" ino=77794 scontext=u:r:rild:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
[  168.907309] type=1400 audit(1588111332.189:477): avc: denied { open } for pid=618 comm="rild" path="/dev/ttyUSB2" dev="tmpfs" ino=77794 scontext=u:r:rild:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
[  168.907340] type=1400 audit(1588111332.189:478): avc: denied { ioctl } for pid=618 comm="rild" path="/dev/ttyUSB2" dev="tmpfs" ino=77794 ioctlcmd=5401 scontext=u:r:rild:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
[  169.852985] init: Received control message 'interface_start' for 'android.hardware.radio.config@1.0::IRadioConfig/default' from pid: 330 (/system/bin/hwservicemanager)
[  169.853056] init: Could not find service hosting interface android.hardware.radio.config@1.0::IRadioConfig/default
```

My manifest is here:

https://github.com/darran-kelinske-fivestars/local-manifest-lineage/blob/TB-8504/manifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Qualcomm use RIL framework different form the usual one.

```
device/qcom/msmxxx/msmxxx.mk
```

add as follow

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += android.hardware.radio.config@1.0-service
```

Comment: Try to use markdown to highlight your `code` accordingly, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I think this might actually be there issue. Will check it out. I am going to give it a try and will report back. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not aware of your application. But I had also faced the same issue when I was building one of the HAL. 
According to your manifest, instance for your HAL will be present in the folder "default" in your HAL package. But if during runtime, if your instance is not created then this error will be thrown.

So, my error went off when I created an instance of my HAL interface in the main.cpp file.

Can you try the same. And recheck whether the folder named "default" is present in your HAL package, and your HAL interface is getting instantiated in the main.cpp file.

Comment: I had to move on to another project, but will try to test this out and report back. Thank you.